# Xamarin Prism nested pages nav and tab bar issues

Tags: c#, xamarin, prism

I want a nav bar with a hamburger menu, preferably one that stays when you navigate from root, with a tabbar on bottom, and a back button that shows when you navigate from root.

- I have /MasterDetailPage/NavigationPage/Tabbed/contentPage
- If I navigate from contentPage to ContentPage1 the Navbar and tabbar disappears when it should just add a back button.
- If I do /master/tabbed/navigation/content  I lose the hamburger menu.
- If I do tabbed/master/navigation/content I lose the tabbar.
- If I do Navigation/master/tabbed/content I just get a blank bar on top.

Ideally I want a bar at the top of my app that always stays with a hamburger menu that always stays, a title image that always stays, and adds a back button when pages are stacked and some pages can add buttons on the right of the top bar. I would also like the tab bar to always be visible.

I have done most of my programming in c,vb,vb.net,perl,python and a little in c++ mostly for embedded firmware. So I am new to C# and to coding on top of a mountain inherited interconnected classes.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You've described a few approaches you've taken in general terms, but this is very open ended and will be difficult to answer as it stands.  In order for the community to be helpful, you'll need to share some code and ask specific questions.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is how would it be done in prism. I am linking the pages together in a logical way and can seem to almost get what I want but then it falls apart when I try to navigate to a new page on to the stack. If it just cant be done I guess I will have to create my own navigation but i am finding the connections between the master page navigation page and navigation bar rather mystical. Any pointers or tips would be welcome.

Comment: Update: Setting useModalNavigation = false when navigating to a sub page kept the navigation bar but I still lost the tab bar. For Clarity NavigationService.NavigateAsync("subpage", useModalNavigation: false);

Comment: Hi @dddienst . Have you solved this issue using Prism? My TabbedPage disappears as well when using NavigateAsync. The application goes to another page and the navigation bar on the top show normally only the TabbedPage in the bottom disappears.